# jQuery number of days between range of dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a form with 2 input text (start & end), both with jquery datapicker.
With jQuery I am tring to get the number of days that fall in a predefined range of dates (two semesters per year) to apply a different rate

```
For ex:

         start-date    end-date       rate

Range A: 01/01/2012 - 06/30/2012  -->  5%
Range B: 07/01/2012 - 12/31/2012  -->  10%  
Range C: 01/01/2013 - 06/30/2013  -->  15%
Range D: 07/01/2013 - 12/31/2013  -->  20%
and so on...

So if date inserted in "start" is = 08/15/2012
and the date inserted in "end" is = 11/20/2013

The number of days per range are:
Range A: 0
Range B: 138 with a rate 10%
Range C: 181 with a rate 15% 
Range D: 143 with a rate 20%
```

So the answer is, how to do something like:

```
(Math.min(end,rangeX_end-date) - Math.max(start,rangeX_start-date))*rangeX_rate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that will help you.. 
Its same usage as sql..

```
function datediff(fromDate,toDate,interval) { 
            var second=1000, minute=second*60, hour=minute*60, day=hour*24, week=day*7; 
            fromDate = new Date(fromDate); 
            toDate = new Date(toDate); 
            var timediff = toDate - fromDate; 
            if (isNaN(timediff)) return NaN; 
            switch (interval) { 
                case "years": return toDate.getFullYear() - fromDate.getFullYear(); 
                case "months": return ( 
                    ( toDate.getFullYear() * 12 + toDate.getMonth() ) 
                    - 
                    ( fromDate.getFullYear() * 12 + fromDate.getMonth() ) 
                ); 
                case "weeks"  : return Math.floor(timediff / week); 
                case "days"   : return Math.floor(timediff / day);  
                case "hours"  : return Math.floor(timediff / hour);  
                case "minutes": return Math.floor(timediff / minute); 
                case "seconds": return Math.floor(timediff / second); 
                default: return undefined; 
            } 
        }
```

scroll down in your updated fiddle here to see "tidyier" version;
http://jsfiddle.net/uUqrT/5/

```
$("#calc").click(function () 
{
    addDaysRow($('#from').val(), $('#to').val());
});

function addDaysRow(fromDate, toDate) {
    var rangeAstart = new Date('01/01/2012');
    var rangeAend = new Date('06/30/2012');
    var rangeBstart = new Date('07/01/2012');
    var rangeBend = new Date('12/31/2012');
    var rangeCstart = new Date('01/01/2013');
    var rangeCend = new Date('06/30/2013');
    var rangeDstart = new Date('07/01/2013');
    var rangeDend = new Date('12/31/2013');

    var diff = datediff(fromDate, toDate, "days");

    $('#record > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>' + diff + '</td><td>' + diff + '</td><td>' +diff + '</td><td>' + diff + '</td><td>' + diff + '</td><td>' + diff + '</td><td>' + diff + '</td></tr>');
}
```

This should start you on the right track - not sure what you want to do with the range here.

Comment: This function count the number of days between two dates, thanks for this. But how to count the number of days trough all ranges?? Something like: return  the number of days that fall in Range A, than in Range B, Than in Range C etc... I have 50 ranges more or less, i have to make 50 var?? Is there a way to use a loop?? Thanks

Comment: Yes of corse, what are you doing with the number of days after this? Can you make a mockup in JSFiddle and tell me what functionality you would like and where? I'll then fill the code. @fasenderos

Comment: Thanks for reply..I have create a fiddle with 4 Ranges..consider that I need to do the same thing with 50 range more or less..as you can see there are a lot of variables and if/else statement.. is there a way to make the same thing with a more "friendly" code?? Here the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fasenderos/uUqrT/4/

Comment: Of course I know that I can reduce the number of vars using an Array, but I prefer to have 2 var for each Range for future implement (every year I need to add 2 Ranges (1 for semester))..the real problem are the if/else statement

Comment: Try my fiddle and then your fiddle with the same dates in the form (for ex 01/01/2012 - 12/31/2013).. my fiddle give the number of days in each range (and it's raight, causa know i can apply the rate), your fiddle return only the total number of days (i don't need that :) )

Comment: "This should start you on the right track - not sure what you want to do with the range here."

Comment: I'm not gonna mess with your ranges, you can use the format as a baseline. i showed you how to get diff between both dates, what else do you need? I dont have time to figure out what is what. you have a better understanding of it than I..

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for it, please refer to attached jsFiddle

```
var start = new Date('2011-04-11');
var end = new Date('2012-04-11');
var diff = Math.round((end- start)/(1000*60*60*24));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4t7DU/